# Initialize elements from list in pandas

Tags: python, list, initialization

I have a list called `x`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = ['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'feature4']
```

I need to initialize each element of that list (without the quote `'`) like this:

```
feature1 = ''
feature2 = ''
feature3 = ''
feature4 = ''
```

Is there a pythonic way of doing so, without having to manually write each element? I am asking because I have a list of 5,783 elements and I cannot write them down manually.

Comment: In which scope do you need to do this? As local variables? As "globals" (module namespace)? The most pythonic way would be to use an explicit object or namespace that would carry them as attributes.  What is the pandas connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
for y in x:
    exec("%s = ''" % (y))
```

Output:

[image]